# gradle.build.kts error while adding room_version in dependencies

Tags: java, android-studio, build.gradle

I am at very beginner level for Andriod Development and using Android Studio Hedgehog now while following a basic To-do List project tutorial. While adding dependencies for room version,I am getting this specific error that I can't identify to solve any way.

"Expecting an element
Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line)"

That how my gradle.build.kts looks like. I'm using Java.

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.mynotesappmvvm"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.mynotesappmvvm"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    def lifecycle_version = "2.7.0'
    def arch_version = "2.2.0"
    def room_version = "2.6.1"
}

dependencies {
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    // ViewModel
    implementation ("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version")
    // ViewModel utilities for Compose
    implementation ("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:$lifecycle_version")
    // LiveData
    implementation ("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_version")
    // Annotation processor
    implementation ("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version")
    implementation ("androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version")
    annotationProcessor ("androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version")
}
```

I have tried few solution but nothing seems to work as it is not identifying these particular lines.
Any one knows what;s going on ...

````
  def lifecycle_version = "2.7.0'
    def arch_version = "2.2.0"
    def room_version = "2.6.1" ```

 and these
````

// ViewModel
implementation ("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version")
// ViewModel utilities for Compose
implementation ("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:$lifecycle_version")
// LiveData
implementation ("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_version")
// Annotation processor
implementation ("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version")
implementation ("androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version")
annotationProcessor ("androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version")

Comment: Your example has a single quote instead of a double quote, so `livecycle_version`'s string doesn't terminate. Not sure if that's just in your question or if it's the actual root of your problem, but either way fix that first.

Answer (score 1):

in your code

```
"2.7.0'
```

you are starting with double quotations and ending in single quotation

do this instead

```
def lifecycle_version = "2.7.0"
def arch_version = "2.2.0"
def room_version = "2.6.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using kotlin based build.gradle.kts, then you have to initialize your variable as,

```
val lifecycle_version = "2.7.0"
val arch_version = "2.2.0"
val room_version = "2.6.1"
```

not as

```
def lifecycle_version = "2.7.0"
def arch_version = "2.2.0"
def room_version = "2.6.1"
```